# Jira: How to get a list of all epics with how many issues each has?

Tags: jira, epics

I want to see a list of all epics in a project ranked by the number of issues in that epic. Is that possible with JQL or otherwise?

We are using Jira Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

**-- For Jira Server --**

In your Issues search section, go to the Columns selector and choose to include the field "Issues in Epic" in your results. Then run this JQL:

```
project = YOUR_PROJECT AND issuetype = Epic ORDER BY "Issues in Epic" ASC
```

The sort does not work properly because (I assume) the field is stored as a string in Jira, so it's in alphabetical order. But you can then export your results as a CSV file and open it with Excel, who has no issues in sorting properly by the numerical value.

Comment: Sorry, I get the error `Not able to sort using field 'Issues in Epic'.`. Is that field only available on Jira Server?

Comment: I got the same error as @fred using Jira Cloud. Tried to see if it would work using "Child issues" but it didn't.

Comment: I'm on Jira Server, yes. But even with Jira Cloud, the difference should be on the hosting, or direct access to the database. But the implementation should be the same. Can you at least see the "Issues in Epic" field in the Columns selector? If you can, you can remove the `ORDER BY "Issues in Epic" ASC`, and then sort in Excel on the exported CSV.

Comment: Can't see it in the column selector unfortunately

Comment: Sounded simple, but I guess too good to be true. Sorry it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query "
project = "" AND issueType = epic ORDER BY issueCount DESC
"

It will return, from highest to lowest a list of all epics in the specified project, ordered by the number of issues in each epic.

you can filter the results to only include epics that have been created in the past week, or epics that are in a specific status.

every query input above but replace the second equals to with " = epic AND created >= 2023-11-10 ORDER BY issueCount DESC

Comment: I get the error: `Not able to sort using field 'issueCount'.`

Comment:  that maybe because the Jira Cloud instance used does not support sorting by the "issueCount" field.